# boolean fail - mesh import and mesh primitive

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I need to trim the cone with the imported mesh. I am able to split the imported mesh with the cone but not the other way around. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Many questions/answers about this kind of things. 2.90 and before has some limitations. 2.91 may correct them.

Comment: worth a try you think?

Comment: Sure 2.91 is just released https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: this didn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Share your file so that people here can have a look. Please use this site and paste the obtained link here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ... and 2.91 has new option for booleans, have you checked it?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=kR5sWZMj" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/kR5sWZMj/)

i didn't know about the new boolean options. i will explore

Comment: It helps when both meshes are close to the same poly density. The imported mesh looks quite dense, try adding a couple of sub-d levels to your cone and try again.
Also, both meshes need to be manifold for a good boolean.

Comment: so if anybody is interested, I was able to perform the boolean operation and create the "wall" with a cube but not a plane nor a regular cone. Maybe that is useful for bug reporting. thanks-